# Clicking using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have these following elements in a page and I need to select the element with the value `18` inside using Python and selenium script. That is the second link. Here is the HTML code of the page

```
<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" href="#">17</a>
<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" href="#">18</a>
<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" href="#">19</a>
```

I am trying to use the following Python and Selenium code to click

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui-state-default"]').click()
```

But that does not work. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("18")
elem.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

That will find the first element matching that XPath, which is the one with the value 17. To select the element whose value is 18, try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('18').click()
```

PS: You don't need to set the click event to a variable. Only do this if you need to multiple actions on the element (`send_keys()`, `click()`, `text`, etc.)